# Action based on field entry for Custom Button in Lightning

Tags: custom-button

I have a custom button and have the following code so that a docusign envelope can be initiated.

Current code works:

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000AMKcEAO"])}
```

But I need it to pick between two actions depending on the value of a field. Not working though.

```
{!IF( Legal_Contract__c.Parent_Company_LC__c = "A",

{!URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000AMKcEAO"])}

, 

{!URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000AMKhEAO"])}

)}
```

Nothing happens when I use the second code. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `{!Experession}` inside your if-true and false block.

```
{!IF( Legal_Contract__c.Parent_Company_LC__c = "A",

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000AMKcEAO"])

, 

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000AMKhEAO"])

)}
```